# Richfaces inputNumberSlider does not call setter

Tags: jsf, richfaces, setter

The following inputNumberSlider does not call my setter:

```
<rich:inputNumberSlider 
         value="#{skinningBean.currentSkin.button.backgroundColor_focussedAlpha}"
         maxValue="1" step="0.1">
         <a4j:ajax event="change" render="preview" oncomplete="initSlider()" />
</rich:inputNumberSlider>


public float getBackgroundColor_focussedAlpha() {
    return backgroundColor_focussedAlpha;
}

public void setBackgroundColor_focussedAlpha(float backgroundColor_focussedAlpha) {
    this.backgroundColor_focussedAlpha = backgroundColor_focussedAlpha;
}
```

I also tried to make a setter which takes a String as parameter, but it's not called as well. Ans yes it is inside a form! What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Seems I'm not the only one with this problem:
http://osdir.com/ml/java-jsf-richfaces-issues/2010-10/msg00073.html

Comment: What version of RF are you running? Have you attempted an upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by your bean's scope.

I've found that if it's anything from the `javax.faces.bean` package the components aren't working, but it will work with the `javax.enterprise.context` package. The scopes are named the same except for `javax.faces.bean.@ViewScoped` which you can change to `javax.enterprise.context.@ConversationScoped`

Comment: This package is not available for me

Comment: @4ndro1d sorry, I made a typo, it's `javax.enterprise.context`

Comment: I'm just getting NullPointer Exceptions when I change my @SessionScoped to it

Comment: What version of Java are you using? The package comes with Java EE 6.

Comment: That's what I'm using. It seems there are problems with the Scope then